# What is technique behind draggable objects?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to learn how to make a div in an HTML page draggable by pure JavaScript not by using external library so I tried some of mine techniques but I failed to make it a proper draggable object. I am sure I'm missing something important in my code so I want to know what is the basic idea behind draggable object. I was trying to achieve it by setting some startX and startY position and making the Div position absolute and setting the left and top of div by css as

```
p.style.left = (e.clientX-startX) + 'px';

p.style.top =  (e.clientY-startY) + 'px';

// where p is the element i am trying to make draggable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not forget to save `p`'s initial position and add it each time to make sure you're doing relative calculations. Currently, you assume `p` is always at position `(0, 0)` when starting dragging.

Secondly, cancelling the `selectstart` event makes for no ugly selection being created when dragging.

I updated your code a bit to this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/rLegF/1/.

```
var p = document.getElementById("p"),
    startX, startY,
    origX, origY,
    down = false;

document.documentElement.onselectstart = function() {
    return false; // prevent selections
};

p.onmousedown = function(e) {
    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;

    origX = p.offsetLeft;
    origY = p.offsetTop;

    down = true;
};

document.documentElement.onmouseup = function() {
    // releasing the mouse anywhere to stop dragging
    down = false;
};

document.documentElement.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // don't do anything if not dragging
    if(!down) return;

    p.style.left = (e.clientX - startX) + origX + 'px';
    p.style.top  = (e.clientY - startY) + origY + 'px';
};
```

**Edit:** You could also combine `startX` and `origX` since you're basically always doing `- startX + origX`: http://jsfiddle.net/rLegF/2/.

What you're then doing is calculating the mouse position with respect to the top left-hand corner of the element, and then set the position to the new mouse position minus that old mouse position. Perhaps it's a little more intuitive that way.

I cleaned up some more as well.

Comment: i'm new to javascript and i'm sorry if this a stupid question but whats the difference here in using different startX and origX and what this OffsetLeft/Top really returns

Comment: @monk: `startX` is the mouse x coordinate when starting dragging. `origX` is the x coordinate of the element when starting dragging. Using both, you can calculate the new position when moving the mouse. `offsetLeft` returns a number indicating the amount of pixels the element is positioned with respect to the left border.